# Input Form Externally

Tags: php, curl, input, field

I'm not sure if I worded the title correctly but here it goes...

This site: http://www.megavideor.com

In the big input field you can enter http://www.megavideo.com/?v=C6IJJDU6 and then click Load Video, and it will load the video on the right hand side.

I want to make a script where I can enter the field and submit it automatically with a url.

Example:

http://www.mydomain.com/SCRIPT.PHP?url=http://www.megavideo.com/?v=C6IJJDU6

And the above link would automatically enter the url and take you to the page with the video ready to watch.

Can anyone tell me how this is done or direct me to what this sort of script is called, so I can try googling it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter data into the url like that it's GET data, not POST data.
The form uses POST data, but it can be changed to use GET data as well.

If you want to keep your forum as is, use $_REQUEST in your php instead of $_POST.
$_REQUEST contains both $_GET and $_POST values.